# How to use BigQuery Standard SQL in Dataflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to run a simple query using [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) within dataflow but I can't find where to enable this option. How can I do that?

```
pipeline.apply(Read.named(metricName + " Read").fromQuery("select * from table1 UNION DISTINCT select * from table2"));
```

When I try to run it I receive the error:

```
2016-07-20T13:35:22.543Z: Error:   (6e0ad847af078af9): Workflow failed. Causes: (fe6c7bcb1a35a057): S01:warehouse_handled_returns Read/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeRead+ParMultiDo(FormatData)+warehouse_handled_returns Write/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIOWrite/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeWrite failed., (7f29f1d9435d27bc): BigQuery execution failed., (7f29f1d9435d2823): Error:
Message: Encountered "" at line 23, column 27.

HTTP Code: 400
```

Comment: This is not supported by the current version of BigQueryIO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now use standard SQL with Dataflow.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io

```
PCollection<TableRow> weatherData = p.apply(
BigQueryIO.Read
.named("ReadYearAndTemp")
.fromQuery("SELECT year, mean_temp FROM `samples.weather_stations`")
.usingStandardSql();
```

Comment: As an FYI, this has been deprecated. Dataflow now is based on the Apache Beam programming model https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/beam-programming-model

Answer (score 1):

Until DataFlow formally supports BigQuery Standard SQL, one workaround is to start query with the following comment:

```
#StandardSQL
```

This will instruct BigQuery to use Standard SQL instead of Legacy SQL

Comment: I tried this, but got the following error - `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow SDK for Java supports BigQuery's Standard SQL dialect beginning in version 1.8.0.

Comment: Standard SQL is now supported.